# Change the number of rows read.table uses to determine the number of column in R

Tags: r, read.table

In `?read.table` is stated that:

```
The number of data columns is determined by looking at the first five lines of input
(or the whole file if it has less than five lines), or from the length of col.names
if it is specified and is longer. This could conceivably be wrong if fill or
blank.lines.skip are true, so specify col.names if necessary (as in the ‘Examples’).
```

I need to use the `fill` paramenter and some of my txt files may have the row with the highest number of column after the 5th row. I can't use an header, just because I don't have it and the col.names will be defined after the import, so I would like to change these 5 rows that R used into the whole file, (I don't mind any speed loss I could get). Any suggestion? Thanks!

EDIT:

just found this in the code of `read.table`

```
if (skip > 0L) 
    readLines(file, skip)
nlines <- n0lines <- if (nrows < 0L) 
    5
else min(5L, (header + nrows))
lines <- .External(C_readtablehead, file, nlines, comment.char, 
    blank.lines.skip, quote, sep)
nlines <- length(lines)
```

can I just change the number `5` in the 4th rows of the above code? is that going to have any side effect on the `read.table` behaviours?

EDIT 2:

I'm currently using this method

```
maxCol <- max(sapply(readLines(filesPath), function(x) length(strsplit(x, ",")[[1]])))
```

to have the max number of columns, and putting the result to create dummy `col.names` like `paste0("V", seq_len(maxCol))`. Do you think is still worth to have another `read.table` with the possibility to chose that?

Comment: What about if you specify which columns to read via `colClasses`?

Comment: Hi, the thing is. I don't know in advance the number of columns (got many files to import, with different number columns per row, so I use `fill`). I could run a `scan` and check the `max(col)` before calling `read.table`, but it'd be more consistent (to me) having the possibility to choose the number of lines to scan (in place of an hard coded `5`)

Comment: Can you provide more details on how and why your source files vary in format so much?  Personally, I'd shoot the dope who created them, but that's occasionally frowned upon.  And why do the row lengths vary so much? If it's a matter of a lot of header/metadata rows prior to a block of data, then  consider using the `skip` argument.  Otherwise, maybe just run `readLines` to load the entire file and then parse it out.

Comment: Just in case someone's reading this, I'm upvoting Carl's comment, but not the shooting part, the `readLines` and parsing part.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I haven't created such files, but I have to work with them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `count.fields`, e.g.,

```
read.table(filesPath, colClasses=rep(NA, max(count.fields(filesPath))), fill=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks!  Once again, a useful function I'd never seen is posted on SO.

Comment: hi ya! thanks. good answer! I'd improved my EDIT2 solution in the mean time doing `max(unlist(lapply(gregexpr(",", readLines(files[j])), length)))`. But yours it's far more elegant and compact. It's also a bt faster, but I don't mind speed so much for this task, since I've got (lots of) very small files.

Comment: one question: using `colClasses` I guess I'll by-pass the script that tries to assign classes in `read.table`. Setting the classes to `NA` will the output be all character columns? thanks.

Comment: No, `NA` tells `R` to use `type.convert` to determine the datatype.

Comment: I see. So, since `colClasses` is not `null` you are telling `R` the number of columns you want, but since you are not actually supplying any data type it'll run `type.convert`.